# A Quick Set Notation Question

Tags: linear-algebra

I've just been asked by a first semester linear algebra student to decide whether the following set is a subspace or not:
$$ \left\{\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset\mathbb{R}|\left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right)\left((-1)^n\times n\geq0\right) \right\} $$

However, I am not sure what the set even is. A set of real sequences where we only "care" about the even terms? I thought perhaps this is a mistake and it really should've been $x_n$ instead of $n$. Am I misunderstanding, or is this likely an error?

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. It's cute. I too wonder if they meant $x_n$.

Comment: Presumably, the "$\Bbb R$" is meant to be $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$, also.

Comment: @DavidMitra I don't like the notation in the problem either, but if it is $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$, then it should $\in$ instead of $\subset$.

Comment: @GitGud Yes. I missed that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take it literally as printed, the condition in the set is always false, so the set is empty and therefore not a subspace.  If you assume it's $x_n$ rather than $n$ then the negative of an element is not generally in the set, so it's still not a subspace.

Comment: Is it always false? I think by now we can conclude that this is almost certainly a mistake, but I think that I am not understanding this *wrong* notation correctly. Could you elaborate on why is it an empty set?

Comment: It's false because it says $(-1)^n\times n\ge0$ **for all** $n\in\Bbb N$.  That is, $-1,2,-3,4,-5$ and so on are **all** non-negative, which is certainly not true.  This condition in fact has nothing to do with the vector $\{x_n\}$, which  is why it's likely that there is a misprint.

Comment: Ah, right, because there's no vertical bar or colon between the two brackets denoting "such that", is that correct?

Comment: There is a vertical bar there, unless there is something badly wrong with my eyesight ;-)  The condition for set membership is everything between $\mid$ and $\}$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I was thinking of an imaginary second vertical bar, having two "such thats". Thanks.